# Cocoa & Cocoa Touch. How do I create an NSData object from a plain ole pointer?

Tags: cocoa-touch, malloc, nsdata, nsoperation

I have malloc'd a whole mess of data in an NSOperation instance. I have a pointer:

```
data = malloc(humungous_amounts_of_god_knows_what);
uint8_t* data;
```

How do I package this up as an NSData instance and return it to the main thread? I am assuming that after conversion to an NSData instance I can simply call:

```
free(data);
```

Yes?

Also, back on the main thread how do I retrieve the pointer?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Barry,

I actually went with something even simpler.

Put an NSValue wrapper around the pointer:

```
NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithPointer:imageData];
```

Stuff it in a dictionary to be returned to the main thread:

```
[result setObject:value forKey:cubicFaceName];
```

Back on the main thread, when I'm done with the data I discard it:

```
uint8_t *bits = [value pointerValue];
free(bits);
```

Cheers,
Doug

Answer (score 1):

You want one of the `-dataWithBytes:length:` or its variants:

```
NSData *d = [NSData dataWithBytes:data length:lengthOfDataInBytes];
```

which copies the bytes and you can then `free(data)`. To save a copy, assuming `data` is allocated using `malloc` use:

```
NSData *d = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:data length:lengthOfDataInBytes];
```

You should *not* call `free` on your buffer in this case, as the `NSData` instance will free it for you.

Note that all of these methods return an `autoreleased` instance, so you will probably have to retain it if you want to keep it around between threads (and aren't using GC). You can use the equivalent `alloc`/`initWithBytes:...` initializers instead.

To get a pointer to an NSData's contents, use `bytes`.

(I think a few minutes with the [`NSData`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation will serve you well)